# No cookie being set Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, cookies

I'm trying to figure out which is the proper way to set a cookie in Symfony 3. After reading posts on here, I figured out it would work like this;

```
$response = new Response();
$cookie = new Cookie("source", "$testing", time()+86400);
$response->headers->setCookie($cookie);
```

Response and Cookie both being HttpFoundation components. However, after setting this in a basic controller;

```
/**
* @Route("/", name="homepage")
*/
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $response = new Response();
        $cookie = new Cookie("source", "testing", time()+86400);
        $response->headers->setCookie($cookie);

        return $this->render('index.html.twig');
    }
```

The cookie is simply not being set at all after visiting the page;

[image: Cookie not being set]

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Someone in the comments asked for a var_dump of $response;

```
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)#370 (6) {
  ["headers"]=> object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag)#371 (5) {
    ["computedCacheControl":protected]=> array(2) {
      ["no-cache"]=> bool(true)
      ["private"]=> bool(true)
    }
    ["cookies":protected]=> array(1) {
      [""]=> array(1) {
        ["/"]=> array(1) {
          ["source"]=> object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie)#372 (9) { 
            ["name":protected]=> string(6) "source"
            ["value":protected]=> string(7) "testing"
            ["domain":protected]=> NULL
            ["expire":protected]=> int(1495910350)
            ["path":protected]=> string(1) "/"
            ["secure":protected]=> bool(false)
            ["httpOnly":protected]=> bool(true)
            ["raw":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie":private]=> bool(false)
            ["sameSite":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie":private]=> NULL
          }
        }
      }
    }
    ["headerNames":protected]=> array(2) {
      ["cache-control"]=> string(13) "Cache-Control"
      ["date"]=> string(4) "Date"
    }
    ["headers":protected]=> array(2) {
      ["cache-control"]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> string(17) "no-cache, private"
      }
      ["date"]=> array(1) {
        [0]=> string(29) "Fri, 26 May 2017 18:39:10 GMT"
      }
    }
    ["cacheControl":protected]=> array(0) { }
  }
  ["content":protected]=> string(0) ""
  ["version":protected]=> string(3) "1.0"
  ["statusCode":protected]=> int(200)
  ["statusText":protected]=> string(2) "OK"
  ["charset":protected]=> NULL
}
```

Comment: Can you `dd($response);` before the return and let us know what you see?

Comment: dd($response) just gives me an UndefinedFunctionException error. "Attempted to call function "dd" from namespace "AppBundle\Controller"."

Comment: Oops, then try `var_dump($response);` instead?

Comment: I appended the var_dump in the question.

Comment: Thanks, the response looks good, and I reckon you figured out what the issue is.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've figured it out. Return expects a response, and the render function gives a full response. In order to put in a cookie, I need to add it to the response generated by render before returning the function as follows;

```
$response = $this->render('index.html.twig');
$cookie = new Cookie("source", "testing", time()+86400);
$response->headers->setCookie($cookie);

return $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to send the response you created. Just add $response->send(); after setting the cookie.

```
    /**
    * @Route("/", name="homepage")
    */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $response = new Response();
        $cookie = new Cookie("source", "testing", time()+86400);
        $response->headers->setCookie($cookie);
        $response->send();

        return $this->render('index.html.twig');
    }
```

Comment: be careful, because this ->send() might flush all the response if "fastcgi_finish_request" is enabled. Better to use sendHeaders() instead

Answer (score 0):

**Symfony 5.4**

I was able to store cookie value as shown below. Similar to @Gerjan's solution

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;


$response = new Response();
//Setting Cookie
$response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('name', 'artisan-bay', time() + (24 * 60 * 60))); // Expiry 1 Day

// Sending the response to the client
$response->send();
```

Read value from cookie

```
$request->cookies->get('name');
```

To delete a cookie, set expiry to past time

```
$response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('name', '', time() - 3600));
```